# Using Rollup + PostCSS + Font Awesome

Tags: font-awesome, rollup, postcss

What would be the appropriate method to allow me to import Font Awesome (from npm `font-awesome`) to allow me to be able to include it and use it from my CSS.

Linking to it directly from `node_modules` wouldn't work, since that wouldn't be available at run-time.

I could also manually copy the font files from `node_modules` and link them that way, but that feels kind of hacky or "old school".

Is there some method to get PostCSS to automatically scoop it up and pull it all into my one JS file?

Comment: https://github.com/dan-gamble/postcss-font-awesome i wrote this which lets me link in the font awesome font file and then just use the icon names on my CSS pseudo classes.